FORMAL derivation of HJB equation in deterministic case (continuous-time setting)
Is there a formal derivation for HJB equation in deterministic and continuous-time setting? I already knew the formal derivation of stochastic and continous-time case from Pham (2009). I checked several books and lecture notes and they all introduced an informal derivation from finite difference method (e.g. Dynamic programming and optimal control by Dimitri Bertsekas, vol 1, chapter 3)
Thank you so much in advance!
